# Append system python installation's sys.path to my personal python installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, module

I have a system python installation and a personal python installation in my home directory. My personal python comes in ahead in my `$PATH` and I usually run that. But the system python installation has some modules that I want to use with my personal python installation.

So, basically, I want to append the `sys.path` of the system python installation to the `sys.path` of the personal python installation.

I read up on the docs and source of site module and saw that I could use the `sitecustomize` or `usercustomize` modules to do this. But where I am stuck is how do I get the `sys.path` of the system python to be appended to the personal python's `sys.path`.

The `gensitepackages` function in the site modules seems to calculate the paths to be added to `sys.path` but it is using the `PREFIXES` global variable instead of taking it as an argument, so for all I know, I can't use it. Adding system python's prefixes to `PREFIXES` is also not an option as by the time the customize module(s) are loaded, the `PREFIXES` is already used to build the path.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Also, I'm not sure if I should ask this on askubuntu/unix&linux. Comments?

**Edit**: Guess I wasn't clear on this part. I want the system python's path to be *appended* so that when I try to use modules that are *not* present in my personal python, it will automatically fallback to the system python's modules.

Comment: can't you just use the `PYTHONPATH` env var?

Comment: @EliBendersky, good suggestion. But that would *prepend* and I want to *append*. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: That's true, `PYTHONPATH` comes before the system defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set the [PYTHONPATH environment variable](http://docs.python.org/py3k/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or, in your personal Python installation's site-packages directory, add one or more [path configuration files](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/site.html) (.pth files) that point to the directories you want to add from the system Python installation.

UPDATE: In general, it's not a good idea to mix modules from different Python instances.  For instance, there could be differences in the configure parameters used to build the two Python that could produce incompatibilities in C extension modules built for the existing system Python but used with your personal Python.  But, if you really want to go down this path, you could manipulate the path with .pth files or modify the `site` module.  Or what might be a more-straightforward and easier-to-manage approach is to use [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create a private virtual environment using the system Python but then replace the interpreter in the environment; see, for example, the section `Using Virtualenv without bin/python`.

Comment: About the PYTHONPATH, it comes in the front of `sys.path`. I want mine to be appended. About the config files, can I guarantee that they are appended to `sys.path`? From what I could gather from the docs, it looks like they are added in alphabetical order.

Comment: You could have figured it out yourself by trying it in the time it took to ask!  Just do an `import sys; print(sys.path)` and see.

Comment: One way to specify a particular order is to use one .pth file and have one line per directory in it in the order you want them imported.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comments. I did run that code you gave several times with many combinations before googling and searching SO and then asking. The docs say `PYTHONPATH` is prepended to `sys.path` so its not solving my problem. And yes, I can give the directories in the `.pth` in order I want, but what I want is that the entries in that `.pth` file should be at the last of `sys.path` so modules are first searched in my personal python and then go to the system python. Please let me know if I am still unclear.

Comment: It appears the directories specified in `.pth` do get appended to the end of `sys.path`.  However, if `setuptools` or its clone `Distribute` are in use, beware that they perform some complex manipulations to manage the order of path directories.  You may not be able to get the exact path order you want without altering the contents of the `setuptools`-managed `easy-install.pth`

Comment: Thanks for that insight Ned. That means I would have to resort to making the path myself in the customize scripts, no?

Comment: Good point about the incompatibilities in C extensions Ned. Didn't think about that one. I think I'll just add the modules that are *only* in system python to a `.pth` file in my personal python, and check if it works. Guess its a bad idea to add all from system python. Thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 1):

python is gonna check if there is a `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable set. Use that for the path of your other modules.

use `export PYTHONPATH="path:locations"`